# Given $a + b - c - d$ and $a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2$, can one compute $a^3 + b^3 - c^3 - d^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose for real numbers $a, b, c, d$ you knew the value of $a + b - c - d$ and $a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2$. Is there a way to extract the value of $a^3 + b^3 - c^3 - d^3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to determine $a^3 + b^3 - c^3 - d^3$ knowing just $a + b - c - d$ and $a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2$. For a simple counterexample, consider the case where:

$$
\begin{align}
a + b - c - d &= 0 \\
a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2 &= 4 \\
\end{align}
$$

The 4-tuples $\,a=1, b=-2, c=-1, d=0\,$ and $\,a=2, b=-1, c=1, d=0\,$ both satisfy the above, but the value of $\,a^3 + b^3 - c^3 - d^3\,$ is $\,-6\,$ for the first 4-tuple vs. $\,6\,$ for the second one.